# Unity & Github Connection

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, github-desktop

I'm trying to co-work with my crews on my indie game project by Github. I created unity project and clone repository on github desktop. After clicking the 'Show in Explorer' button next to the 'View the files of your repository in Explorer' and copy my unity project files.

But after chaning my code of the scripts, github desktop doesn't catch the change of the code. It's my first time actually using github so can anyone help me out on this?

Thanks

Comment: how do you mean "and copy my unity project files"?

Comment: @BugFinder .Ctrl c all the files included in my project's folder and pasted to the clone repository folder.

Comment: eww. you're supposed to open the cloned stuff with unity and edit it there...  I havent used githubs own desktop client, but, id ditch the whole thing, start again, and then point unity to that folder and edit and get the hang of how the github client works before doing serious work

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried the method that you came up with but have a problem of not able to commit to the 20674 changed files just by opening the new unity project. I set the repo's gitignore unity properly. Can you help me on this issue?

Comment: Well. Least it saw changes but that sounds odd. It sounds like no meta files were included and you can commit 20k changes with git

Comment: Out of interest if you "just opened it in unity" what are the changes. It doesnt sound like the gitignore is included

Comment: "It doesnt sound like the gitignore is included"

Agreed.

Please post the contents of your gitnore and where it is in your directory structure. Check that the ignored directories and files are properly placed relative to the .gitignore.

Consider looking into this one and reading the rationale behind the different parts of it: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore